# Docker Local Volume Driver options

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am creating docker volume using docker local volume driver but docker documentation has limited information about what options are available like below. How do I know what options I should use and what are the options available.

`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 foo`

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `--driver local` (the default), they're the standard [Linux **mount**(8) options](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).  In most cases you don't need any at all; it is sufficient to just run

```
docker volume create foo
```

or the equivalent Docker Compose

```
volumes:
  foo:
```

The only particularly notable option for routine use is that setting `--opt o=bind --opt device=/some/source/dir` uses Linux mount options to create a bind mount in a Docker named volume.  This is very similar to the shorter Docker `-v /some/source/dir:/container/dir` bind-mount syntax.

Comment: Thanku David ..i got it  i have one thing now while creating nfs mount point docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
    foo ...  from where i will knw tht this has " addr" as a parameter this is what confusing me because mount man page dont have this option ???

Comment: See the "mount options" section in [nfs(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html).

Comment: What about setting the uid of gid of the volume? Docker seems to require setting the device when you specify uid, do you happen to know what default value that should be or is that machine specific?

Comment: Where in the docker documentation is it mentioned that `local` driver uses the linux `mount` option.

Comment: @MissakaIddamalgoda
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Answer (score 10):

Based on the answer by @DavidMaze and other comments on the answer.

The `local` Driver has options that is platform dependent. As for the Docker Docs

> The built-in local driver on Windows does not support any options.
>
> The built-in local driver on Linux accepts options similar to the linux mount command. You can provide multiple options by passing the --opt flag multiple times.

But if you using `WSL 2` Backend for Docker in Docker for Windows there is a chance these options for linux might work.

You can view options supported by Linux mount command through here [mount(8) — Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)

You can pass these options to the Docker CLI using the `--opt` flag as follows

```
docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=tmpfs \
--opt device=tmpfs \
--opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
foo
```

This creates a tmpfs volume called foo with a size of 100 megabyte and uid of 1000

The same can be achieved in Docker Compose as follows

Docker Compose File v3

```yaml
volumes:
  foo:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "tmpfs"
      o: "o=size=100m,uid=1000"
      device: "tmpfs"
```

There are also additional Filesystem specific mount options that might be helpful for you.
[FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC_MOUNT_OPTIONS)

References:

- [docker volume create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) - [Driver-specific options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options)
- Docker Compose File v3 - [Volume configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference)